# How to Open Mobile Browsers on Android and Apple iOS devices using Appium Library, Robotframework(python) and Saucelabs

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, robotframework, saucelabs

I wish to open mobile browsers (device browser on android phones and safari on apple ios phones) using Appium Library in Robotframework (Python) and SauceLabs.

I can get the Desired Capabilities from the Saucelabs Platform Configurator.

But I cannot pass them along with the ${remote_url} and ${desired_capabilities} to the "Open Browser" method.

When I do, it launches the mobile device emulator/simulator and the browser but does not input the URL in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

### After many hours of trials, here are the steps that did the magic:

For iOS,

```
**** Settings ****
Suite Setup    Set Library Search Order    Selenium2Library
Test Setup    Open page
Test Teardown    Close Page
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections
Library    SauceLabs
Library    requests
Library    AppiumLibrary

**** Test Cases ****
Test_case_sample

**** Keywords ****
Open Page
    ${desired_capabilities}=    Create Dictionary
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceName    iPhone 6 Simulator
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    build    test_run
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    platformName    iOS
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    name    test_name
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    platformVersion    10.0
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceOrientation     portrait
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    browserName    Safari
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    appiumVersion    1.6.3
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceType    phone
    ${executor}=    Evaluate          str('http://my_sauce_username:my_sauce_access_key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub')
    Create Webdriver    Remote      desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}    command_executor=${executor}
    Go To    https://www.google.com

Close Page
    Run Keyword If    '${REMOTE_URL}' != ''    Report Sauce Status    ${SUITE_NAME} \| ${TEST_NAME}    ${TEST_STATUS}    ${TEST_TAGS}    ${REMOTE_URL}
```

### Close All Browsers

For Android, 
just change the following desired capabilities:

```
**** Settings ****
Suite Setup    Set Library Search Order    Selenium2Library
Test Setup    Open page
Test Teardown    Close Page
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections
Library    SauceLabs
Library    requests
Library    AppiumLibrary

**** Test Cases ****
Test_case_sample

**** Keywords ****
Open Page
    ${desired_capabilities}=    Create Dictionary
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceName    Android Emulator
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    build    test_run
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    platformName    Android
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    name    test_name
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    platformVersion    5.1
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceOrientation     portrait
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    browserName    Browser
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    appiumVersion    1.5.3
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceType    phone
    ${executor}=    Evaluate          str('http://my_sauce_username:my_sauce_access_key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub')
    Create Webdriver    Remote      desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}    command_executor=${executor}
    Go To    https://www.google.com

Close Page
    Run Keyword If    '${REMOTE_URL}' != ''    Report Sauce Status    ${SUITE_NAME} \| ${TEST_NAME}    ${TEST_STATUS}    ${TEST_TAGS}    ${REMOTE_URL}
```

### Close All Browsers

For additional mobile device capabilities, please refer to Saucelabs Platform Configurator

Comment: Could you post the code in text format instead of an image? It's more helpful that way ...

Comment: @Goralight - Apparently I just started posting answers and am new to the features. When I first uploaded the script in text format, it did not preserve the format. Hence I uploaded later as an image. I will check how to paste it in text format and still preserve the format. Will do it as time permits.

Comment: Updated Answer such that code can be copied as text by users.